# Loop to remove the same letter of each row

Tags: python, pandas, loops

In Python, if I want to add a letter in each row of a column, I use this:

```
df = df.assign(Meses=[f'M{i}' for i in df.Meses])

               Meses  
1               M1  
2               M2   
3               M3    
4               M4   
5               M5    
6               M6   
7               M7    
8               M8   
9               M9    
10              M10    
11              M11
```

How can I do the opposite (remove the "m" of each row of a certain column)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = df.assign(Meses=[mi[1:] for mi in df.Meses])
```

should work.

EDIT:
But as suggested by @harvpan,

```py
df['Meses'] = df['Meses'].astype(str).str[1:]
```

might be consequently faster because it is entirely pandas native.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you (10 minutes to accept this answer)

Answer (score 3):

This should be much faster:

```
df['Meses'] = df['Meses'].astype(str).str[1:]
```

Output:

```
   Meses
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
11  11
```